# Can this code be shortened? Custom time status with emojis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a custom status where you can see the time in real time, and the emoji of the clock indicating that same time, I have done it, and it is functional, but I would like to know if there is any way to abbreviate this code, or is it already as efficient as possible? Thanks

```
import time

emoji = ""
emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "",
          "", "", "", "", "", "",
          "", "", "", "", "", "",
          "", "", "", "", "", ""]


while True:
    hour= time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    hm = int(time.strftime('%I')) + int(time.strftime('%M'))/100

    if 1 <= hm < 1.30:
        emoji = emojis[0]
    elif 1.30 <= hm < 2:
        emoji = emojis[1]
    elif 2 <= hm < 2.30:
        emoji = emojis[2]
    elif 2.30 <= hm < 3:
        emoji = emojis[3]
    elif 3 <= hm < 3.30:
        emoji = emojis[4]
    elif 3.30 <= hm < 4:
        emoji = emojis[5]
    elif 4 <= hm < 4.30:
        emoji = emojis[6]
    elif 4.30 <= hm < 5:
        emoji = emojis[7]
    elif 5 <= hm < 5.30:
        emoji = emojis[8]
    elif 5.30 <= hm < 6:
        emoji = emojis[9]
    elif 6 <= hm < 6.30:
        emoji = emojis[10]
    elif 6.30 <= hm < 7:
        emoji = emojis[11]
    elif 7 <= hm < 7.30:
        emoji = emojis[12]
    elif 7.30 <= hm < 8:
        emoji = emojis[13]
    elif 8 <= hm < 8.30:
        emoji = emojis[14]
    elif 8.30 <= hm < 9:
        emoji = emojis[15]
    elif 9 <= hm < 9.30:
        emoji = emojis[16]
    elif 9.30 <= hm < 10:
        emoji = emojis[17]
    elif 10 <= hm < 10.30:
        emoji = emojis[18]
    elif 10.30 <= hm < 11:
        emoji = emojis[19]
    elif 11 <= hm < 11.30:
        emoji = emojis[20]
    elif 11.30 <= hm < 12:
        emoji = emojis[21]
    elif 12 <= hm < 12.30:
        emoji = emojis[22]
    elif 12.30 <= hm < 13:
        emoji = emojis[23]


    print(f"{emoji} {hour}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yes, it could be simplified. I'd do it by taking a modulus of the minutes in a 12-hour day to give you an integer between 0&23 und use that to index the `emojis` list. However, this is not the place to ask how to do it, really.

Comment: You could have a dictionary of the times e.g `{"1:00": "", "1:30": "", ...}` and a function that converts the current time to the nearest half hour that then looks up the corresponding emoji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be a little off on the indices, however the following approach has some improvements.

```
import time

emojis = ""

while True:
    hour= time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    hm = int(time.localtime().tm_hour + time.localtime().tm_min / 30 + 0.5)
    print(f"{emojis[hm]} {hour}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Cheers, I feel there is more room to trim further, however perhaps at the cost of readability.